# How to do ng-bind without wrapper div?

Tags: angularjs

As in the  documentation it is like some div or html tags wrapping out the expression.
http://docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com/api/ng.directive:ngBind
Is there a way to just get the expression value without the  or  whatsoever wrapper it?

Comment: {{ expressionValue }}

Comment: Yes but I am more concerned about ng-bind and ng-bind-template here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngBind` is a directive, and all directives must be attached to a tag. So no, there's no way to use `ngBind` itself without putting it on some kind of tag.

As mentioned, you can use string interpolation in the form of `{{expression}}` instead.

`ngBindTemplate` exists because some HTML elements don't allow child elements, so `{{expression}}` may not work correctly. In those cases, you put `ngBindTemplate` on the element; it doesn't make sense to use it without a "wrapper" element.

Comment: I believe Angular is adding support for comment-based directives (not sure what version).

Comment: @AndrewHo `M - Comment: <!-- directive: my-directive exp -->` comment directive is already supported. http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you can't just use the curly brace notation `{{expression}}`?

Comment: Actually just for aesthetic reason and habit. But I am asking since I guess there might be simple way to do this even with ng-bind that I  have missed.

Comment: You could easily make your own `replace-with` directive that will simply replace itself with a given expression upon compilation. But no, like Brandon Tilley mentioned there isn't a way to do what you ask with `ng-bind`

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is in the context of `ng-bind-html`, but still relevant and hopefully useful to someone.

I was hitting this with a wrapper `div` breaking my CSS.

After lots of trial and error, came up with the solution of using a custom directive to replace the element with the desired html.

```js
;(function (angular) {
   'use strict'

   angular.module('app').directive('asReplaceElementWithHtml', replaceElementWithHtml)

   function replaceElementWithHtml() {
      return {
         link: replaceElementWithHtmlLink,
      }
   }

   function replaceElementWithHtmlLink(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.replaceWith(attrs.ngDataHtml)
   }
})(angular)
```

Use it like this:

```html
<div
   as-replace-element-with-html
   ng-data-html=`{{:: stringOfHtmlFromTrustedSource}}`
></div>
```